# How to add CSS class to ng2-smart-table <td>?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

How do you add a CSS class to an ng2-smart-table `<td>` for particular column? How can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement.children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('ngx-payer-name-column')[0].closest('td'), 'payer-desc-resident-shown')
```

Comment: have you read the documentation? https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation but didn't find any specific to solve this issue.